# disable block selection in uIWebview

Tags: iphone

sometimes in a webview , a user has to catch partial selection in a para. I am trying to do a partial selection, but instead it selects the entire para with that blue box. Is there a way to get around this ?

Regards
Harikant Jammi

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the paragraph css property display to inline-block. This allows partial text select, but can break the layout, so isn't a solution for all cases.

```
P {
    display:inline-block;
}
```